# how to disable a pageload property under certain circumstances

Tags: asp.net, events, button, gridview, pageload

In .NET i have a gridview which has to display on the mainpage with default settings. So i put it in pageload code. In the same page i have a "List" button; people choose date etc. and when they press the button gridview loads data from another stored procedure. I put that code under List button event. But after people press List button and gridview comes with the needed data, if they press something else (because of page refresh itself) gridview turns back to default settings.

How do i keep the gridview with wanted data?

**protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {**

```
    opsbelgegridview.DataSource = DB.OpsHavuzGetir();
    opsbelgegridview.DataBind();
```

**protected void listelebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {**

```
    opsbelgegridview.DataSource = DB.OpsHavuzDetayListeleBtn(tarih1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), tarih2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), durumdd.SelectedItem.Text.ToString(), islemtipdd.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());
    opsbelgegridview.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IsPostBack()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and only load the initial grid on the first load of the page.  Then if the grid data changes it will stay.

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        opsbelgegridview.DataSource = DB.OpsHavuzGetir();
        opsbelgegridview.DataBind();
    }
}
```